# When do planets formed via core accretion in a proto-planetary disk stop gaining mass?

Tags: astrophysics, planets, stellar-evolution, exoplanets

I was just trying to go over some of the contents in my exo planets course and wanted to know that if all the planets that form via core accretion continue to attract all the dust in a proto-planetary disk via gravity, till the star gets bright enough to expel the material, or if they gather most of their mass from the material swept out in their orbits through the disk, and once this is swept out completely, they stop gaining significant amounts of mass.

Example:

I dont believe that the planets in this system will gain much more mass since the rings seem to be devoid of material. This means that the planets have accreted all the material in their respective orbits. Is this true?

[image]

Comment: Here's a related question from our Astronomy sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23089/16685 which asks about asteroids & other small solar system bodies. There's a link in the answer there to an excellent paper by Cuzzi, Hogan, and Bottke (2010) which attempts to model the accretion processes in the early solar system. Their primary goal was to produce a model that's consistent with the observed size distribution of asteroids & KBOs.